# Standard Required field validation reporting field is empty after upgrade to Sitecore 9.0 Update-2

Tags: validation

We're getting an interesting validation error after upgrading from Sitecore 8.2 Update-6 to Sitecore 9 Update-2.

We have the standard `Required` validator on a field (item name of the field is `Title`). When the workflow validation triggers it says the field has no value, but doing a manual validation shows that it validates fine.

In both the editor and the admin dbbrowser tool the field has a value. Checking the item template's raw values I've confirmed that the validation points to the same items.

The validation on this field hasn't changed in any way since we were on Sitecore 8.2 Update-6, nor has the workflow, and going back to old items and trying to publish them no longer works, because of the same validation issue.

How can I determine where Sitecore 9.x is now getting the idea that the populated field doesn't actually have a value, with the out of the box `Required` validator?

Comment: If you have not already, make sure to log the issue at support to get the team investigating.

Comment: I am also getting the same issue, we have Sitecore 9 update 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sitecore Support has determined that this is a bug, [public reference number](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/853187) 221523.

While previously it was necessary to [contact Sitecore Support](https://support.sitecore.net/) if you ran into this issue, Sitecore's Knowledge Base has [an article covering this issue, with the necessary hotfix](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/527534).

This issue is resolved in 9.1.

Comment: How can we check the status of this bug?

Comment: @Ali contacting Sitecore Support and referencing the public reference number above seems to be the best next step. When I asked, "This is a new bug and I am not aware if this fix will be included in the nearest release. Please review the release notes (when new updates of Sitecore platform will be available on the "dev.sitecore.net") to find out the information about specific fixes that your organization requires."

Comment: Did they give you step to fix or you are waiting for the next update?

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to put that in my answer. If you contact support and tell them the issue you're running into, and reference that number, I believe they'll probably have you provide information to help determine that you're running into the same issue. I received a new DLL that resolved the issue after doing so. Perhaps the more people that report this issue the more likely it will be that it'll end up in 9.0.next.

Comment: James, we also contacted Sitecore support and they sent us the Sitecore.Kernal.dll file and it fixed the issue. thank you for your help.

Comment: For reference Sitecore have provided the patches publicly here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/527534

Comment: Thanks @Svenkle, I've updated the answer accordingly. :)