# Publishing workflow required field error

Tags: sitecore-client, publishing, workflow

I am creating an approval workflow in sitecore 9.0
I am using existing "Sample Workflow" for testing as it provides everything required for approval workflow.

I have created a template with 2 simple single line text fields
1 - title (required)
2 - description (required)

In standard values of individual fields, I am adding the required field validation rule and also setup the "Sample Workflow" as the default workflow. I did not put $name in the title field and description field is also empty. when I save I get warning that fields are required but I thing I will provide there values in actual content page not in standard values.

Now I am creating a content page based on the template and filling value for both fields, when I click on "Validation" link on the review tab, I see all ok. I can submit the page without any error but when I try to approve, I get both fields are required error message and cant submit.

Is workflow/template not configured properly?

**Update**: I have enabled gutter for validation and I can see a required field error indicator but field is not empty, it got some text.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not configured correctly. It's important to realise, Sitecore works with validators on many levels. That is to say, you can make the field required on many different levels, all of them acting independently of each other.

1. The Quick Action / Gutter bar

[image]

This result of validators here, are shown in the gutter on the left. As you've also seen.

2. The Validate Button

[image]

The results of validators defined here, are shown when you press the "Validation" button on the "Review" ribbon.

3. The Validator Bar

[image]

This defines the validators that get triggered when you "Save" an item. Non-admin users will not be able to save items with validation errors. Admin users *will* be allowed. Be aware of this when testing.

4. Workflow

[image]

Finally there are the Workflow Validators. The validators defined here, apply to when you're moving an item through workflow.

### In summary

You either do not have the correct validators set up for Workflow OR (and probably this) you are logged in as an admin and are bypassing workflows.

Another possible problem could be, if you have Language Fallback enabled. If you do, you need to disable it and try your workflow again.

More on validation here: [Sitecore Validation Examples](http://sitecoreworld.blogspot.com/2014/12/sitecore-validation-examples.html)

Comment: I am not logged in with administrator, I have a user "author" and "approver" with appropriate permissions. It could be a bug as stated here, I will contact Sitecore support today and update. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13191/standard-required-field-validation-reporting-field-is-empty-after-upgrade-to-sit/13336?noredirect=1#comment20671_13336

Comment: We have contacted Sitecore support and they sent us the Sitecore.Kernal.dll file and it fixed the issue. thank you for your help.